Load Flow Analysis Issue in IEEE 34-Bus Model on MATLAB Simulink
I am working on the IEEE 34-bus distribution network using MATLAB Simulink. I am using the system provided in the link below:
"https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/123220-ieee-34-bus-distribution-feeder-discrete-simulink-model?s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_ieee%2034"
When I try to perform load flow analysis for the model, the results appear to get stuck at the bus associated with the voltage regulator. As a result, I cannot obtain load flow results for all the buses.
What might be causing the issue with the voltage regulator in the simulation?
Are there any specific settings or adjustments required for the voltage regulator to enable successful load flow analysis?
Any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

What do you mean "the results get stuck at the bus"? Can you [edit] your question so that we might be able to diagnose it without downloading and running that model ourselves?
